# c# Generics property filter

Tags: c#, generics

I'm new to Generics and trying to figure out an issue.

I've created an abstract class with methods for database CRUD methods to use on repository classes for a specific type e.g. Blog, Post etc. I'm looking to create a filter in the search method from a value on an interface property 'ClassType' that's implemented in each class passed to the abstract class .

The abstract class definition is as follows:

```
public abstract class RepositoryCrudBase<T> : IRepositoryCrudBase<T>  where T : class
```

and the search method definition is :

```
public  async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
```

Within the GetAllAsync method I want to be able to do a LINQ 'where' filter using the 'ClassType' on the base type for each class e.g.

```
.Where(t => t.ClassType == typeof(T).Name)
```

but `ClassType` is not an available property in the query

I have discovered that I can modify the method signature to the following and the query works as expected:

```
public  async Task<IQueryable<T>> GetAllAsync<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where) where T : IModelBase
```

but this means I'm passing the base type into the abstract class itself, and then again into the method, which is not ideal.

Is there a way to query using the 'ClassType' property that's passed to the abstract class instead of adding the 'where T : IModelBase' part to the method?

Comment: Your problem reminds me of OfType<T> (see below) is this correct?

If you have a collection containing objects of different types you can use OfType<T> to filter out only those of that type T. Please note that T is not a property on the type T self.
See link for examples

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=net-5.0#examples

Comment: I see no problem in using the constraint `where T : IModelBase`: you need to access a property of the object, and you know that that object will always have that property because you T wll always be somethin implementing IModelBase: let also the compiler kwow it and avoid any cast.

Comment: I agree that adding the annotation is not necessarily an issue, but it means I'm passing the type to the class, and then to the method.

I'm trying to understand if this is the only option, or is it possible to set the annotation on the parent abstract class, and then be able to do the 'where' query using the type passed to the class?

Comment: @GeraldSt Why do you say it "passes the type to the class"?  You're only constraining the type.  Will you ever pass in an object that does not inherit from `IModelBase`?

Comment: Also, If the value of `ClassType`is just the name of the type of every `t` you may use a simpler `.Where(t => t.GetType() == typeof(T))`:(no need for the ClassType property) would it work in your scenario?

Comment: Sorry Amy, badly worded. Yes it's constraining the type, which makes the property available in the where clause

Comment: @GeraldSt And what is is undesirable about the generic constraint?

Comment: @amy It's not undesirable as such, I'm just trying to understand if it's the only way to do the query based on the property on the base type. I'd prefer to be able to just use the type used with the class - I'm possibly misunderstanding what's possible?

Comment: What do you mean by " I'd prefer to be able to just use the type used with the class".  I think there's a misunderstanding here.  If you want every possible type passed into this method to have a `ClassType` property, you do that by constraining the type.  The generic type constraint guarantees that `T` will implement `IModelBase`, which has that property.

Comment: Adding the constraint doesn't really modify the code's runtime behavior. All it does is (#1) cause a compilation error if you try to use a `T` that isn't an `IModelBase`, and (#2) since it can be sure it is an `IModelBase` (because of #1), it allows you to access the members of `IModelBase`. There is nothing new passed in or out of anything.

Comment: You seem concerned with the generic on the method *and* the class. Can you not just have your **class's** constraint be `where T: IModelBase`? That would seem the most obvious thing to do, so perhaps I'm not understanding you.